# how can I calculate frequency of visits for a web page

Tags: javascript, express, time, momentjs

I need to calculate the frequency of visits for a web page, I'm using ExpressJS, mongoDB and PugJS

Assuming that I'm storing each access **date** or **timestamp** in an array in the DB, like the following:

- First Time: Jan 01 2020 12:00:00
- Second Time: Jan 03 2020 15:00:00
- Third Time: Jan 06 2020 15:00:00
- Fourth Time: Jan 08 2020 22:00:00

**And After that it should say**

Frequency of Visits: "Every 7 minutes" or "Every 7 Days" or "Every 2 months" or "Every 3 Days" ... etc.

How can I do that? Please advise.

Comment: are you storing each access date in an array?

Comment: @sonEtLumiere Yes

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a little bit of math. Just calculate the average of the difference between the timestamps. An example:

```js
const visits = [1592512909123, 1592512910123, 1592512901223, 1592512912753];

let average = 0;
for (let i = 1; i < visits.length; i++){
  average += visits[i] - visits[i-1];
}
average /= visits.length - 1;

console.log(`The site gets visited every ${average / 1000} seconds.`);
```

You can then convert the average to seconds/minutes/hours/days.

Answer (score 1):

i hope this helps. You can get the difference between dates in miliseconds and then pass a function to convert miliseconds to second, minutes, hours or years.

```js
var dates = ["Jun 01 2020 12:00:00", "Jun 03 2020 15:00:00", "Jun 06 2020 15:00:00", "Jun 08 2020 22:00:00"];
var fechas = [];
for(i=0; i<dates.length; i++){
 fechas.push(new Date(dates[i]));
}
console.log(fechas);

function convertMiliseconds(miliseconds, format) {
  var days, hours, minutes, seconds, total_hours, total_minutes, total_seconds;
  
  total_seconds = parseInt(Math.floor(miliseconds / 1000));
  total_minutes = parseInt(Math.floor(total_seconds / 60));
  total_hours = parseInt(Math.floor(total_minutes / 60));
  days = parseInt(Math.floor(total_hours / 24));

  seconds = parseInt(total_seconds % 60);
  minutes = parseInt(total_minutes % 60);
  hours = parseInt(total_hours % 24);
  
  switch(format) {
 case 's':
  return total_seconds;
 case 'm':
  return total_minutes;
 case 'h':
  return total_hours;
 case 'd':
  return days;
 default:
  return { d: days, h: hours, m: minutes, s: seconds };
  }
};

var milisecondsDiference = fechas[1] - fechas[0];
console.log(convertMiliseconds(milisecondsDiference, 'h'));  //Output 51 hours
```